# Sql Server Configuration Manager

Tags: sql-server, native-client, configuration-manager

I have two SQL Server named instances, `InstanceA` and `InstanceB` on one computer, and they correctly show up under `Sql Server Configuration Manager` | `SQL Server Network Configuration`.

However, when I try to configure `SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration` | `Client Protocols`, there is no option to specify to which instance the setting will be applied. It appears that this is server (machine) level setting that would apply to every instance installed on it.

Am i missing something here? How to allow one protocol, say `Named Pipes` only for `InstanceA` and `TCP/IP` only for `InstanceB`? (without using `aliases`, preferably)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing Server Network Protocols and Client Network Protocols. Essentially, Server Network Protocols change the way in which SQL Server *listens* for incoming requests and Client Network Protocols change the way in which an application *sends* a request to SQL Server.

As the Client Network Protocols are a shared component and apply to all applications that use that library you cannot set a different protocol per instance that you wish to connect to.

Direct from the Client Network Protocols link below:

> At the simplest level, a SQL Server client can reside on the same machine as an instance of SQL Server. Typically, however, a client connects to one or more remote servers over a network. The client/server architecture of SQL Server allows it to seamlessly manage multiple clients and servers on a network. The default client configurations suffice in most situations.

More information regarding the two can be found in the links below:

[Server Network Protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-network-configuration)

[Client Network Protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/client-network-configuration)

Comment: thanks.  So it is not possible to restrict application connections to an instance to be using a particular protocol in sql Server Configuration Manager?

Comment: It could be done, but you would have to use multiple client machines with each one configured for a specific protocol. You could not do it with a single machine.

Comment: Thanks. What is a Client Tool Connectivity? It seems like something that can be used to configure what protocols to use when the clients are connecting to a server.

Comment: Installs components for communication between clients and servers, and network libraries for DB-Library, ODBC, and OLE DB.